# Using Riemann-Roch Theorem to show every elliptic curve can be written as a plane cubic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, cryptography, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I've been studying how to show that every elliptic curve can be written as a plane cubic through the book of Joseph H. Silverman "Arithmetic Elliptic Curves", the proof of proposition III.3.1 (a) on page 64:
[image: proposition 3.1]

And the start of the proof:

[image: proof of (a)]

My questions are the following

1. Why do we start by looking at the vector spaces $\mathscr{L}(n(O))$?
2. Why do we look at the particular cases of $n=2$ and $n=3$ (i.e. $\mathscr{L}(2(O))$ and $\mathscr{L}(3(O))$)
3. Given the general formula for a cubic, how and why do we restrict ourselves to the 7 functions $1,x,y,x^2,xy,y^2,x^3$?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What experience with elliptic curves do you have so far? Good answers to "why" questions can depend on your background.

Comment: Dear @KReiser, on elliptic curves particularly, it's very minimal knowledge since I started studying it very recently. I think I have a good idea of the geometry of cubic curves, the group law of elliptic curves and some theorems (namely Nagell-Lutz and Mordell's Theorem). The book I started with was Silverman and Tate's "Rational Points on Elliptic Curves". I also have a small background on projective spaces

Comment: This doesn’t have anything to do with the group law. The only special thing about elliptic curves used here is the genus. The point is that Riemann-Roch tells us existence of these functions, and the dimension of  L(6(O)) gives us a linear dependence which yields the desired question. In general for any smooth proper curve, Riemann-Roch tells us the existence of an embedding of some form into some sufficiently large projective space. This is a general theme in algebraic geometry of “ample line bundles”.

Comment: Part 3 is just an instance of a numbers game. For a different example consider the case of $g=3$, $x\in \mathcal{L}(3(0))\setminus \mathcal{L}(2(0))$, $y\in  \mathcal{L}(4(0))\setminus \mathcal{L}(3(0))$ (assuming such $x,y$ exist, in this case not guaranteed by Riemann-Roch). Then we have $1,x,y,x^2,xy,y^2, x^3, x^2y, xy^2,y^3,x^4$ all in $ \mathcal{L}(12(0))$. That is, eleven functions in a space of dimension $12+1-g=10$. Again, we get a linear dependence relation.